# NameError: name 'Class' is not defined, How to access in a class it same name in Django?

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

models.py file that contain the Category  model with name, description parent_category fields

```
class Category(models.Model):
    """ Categories representation model """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()
    parent_category = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
```

serializers.py file, that container the Category model serializer with all it fields

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """ product categories model serializer """
    parent_category = CategorySerializer()
    class Meta:
        """ profile model serializer Meta class """
        model = Category
        fields = (
            'id',
            'name',
            'description',
            'parent_category'
        )
```

views.py file, API view to get all available categories with required user authentication

```
class GetCategoriesView(APIView):
    """ product categories getting view """
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """ get request method """
        categories = Category.objects.all()
        serializer = CategorySerializer(categories, many=True, context={'request':request})
        return Response(data=serializer.data, status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

Expectected result, Json result with a recursive data from the parent_category field

```
{
    name:'boy shoes',
    description:'boy shoes category description'
    parent_category:{
        name:'shoes',
        description:'shoes category description',
        parent_category:{
            name:'clothes',
            description:'clothes category description',
            parent_category: null
        }
    }
}
```

Error i get, i noticed that i can't access directly the Class inside the same class

```
NameError: name 'CategorySerializer' is not defined
```

How can i solve that?, i think you can help solve that issue

> Thank you for your attention :)

Comment: Can you show the whole views file?

Comment: Why do you have the line `parent_category = CategorySerializer()` in `CategorySerializer` class ? As the error stack is not specified in the description, I guess that's where the error occurs.

Comment: by default, it will render just the id of parent_category like {name:'category', description:'category description', parent_category:3}, so if i want to custom it as a json i must specify it Serializer class

Answer (score 1):

You can't use same class as class variable. Just for info

```py
class SomeClass:
    x = SomeClass() # won't work NameError: name 'SomeClass' is not defined
    
    def __init__(self):
        x = SomeClass() # this is OK
```

So you have to change your serializer to something like this

```py
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """ product categories model serializer """

    class Meta:
        """ profile model serializer Meta class """
        model = Category
        fields = (
            'id',
            'name',
            'description',
            'parent_category'
        )

    def get_fields(self):
        fields = super().get_fields()
        fields['parent_category'] = CategorySerializer()
        return fields
```